# can flutter adjust widget size automatically in different device?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new in flutter and haven't used `android` before. When I complete pages, I simply set the width and height of a widget according to the XD designed by UI designers. As I know UI designers usually set the size according to some one phone type. My question is: If the flutter program run in different devices, how can I change widgets' size automatically to adapt to the phone(or ipad). As we can imagine, if my program is based on ipad mini(1024x768), the designed widget size will be a little big, then some error maybe occur if I run the program in a samller device(like modbile phone) I think. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you seen: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive

Answer (score 0):

If all widget's are placed static and have proportional size, then you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil, this library or MediaQuery widget.

Or design have ratio size, then you can use Flexible and Expandable widgets as you need.